# Right tail decay of F distribution

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, asymptotics

Suppose $X\sim F(a,b)$. Is there any sharp upper bound of the following probability with large $x$?
$$\mathbb{P}(X\geq x)$$
what is the order of the above probability as $x\to+\infty$?

Comment: What's $F(a,b)$?

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 3):

The pdf of the [$F$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution) $F_{a,b}$ with $a,b$ degrees of freedom is given by 
\begin{equation}
 f(x)= c\, x^{a/2-1} (a x+b)^{-a/2-b/2} 
\end{equation}
for $x>0$, where $c:=a^{a/2} b^{b/2}/B\left(\frac{a}{2},\frac{b}{2}\right)$. Replacing here $a x+b$ by $ax$, we get the upper bound 
\begin{equation}
 g(x):=ca^{-a/2-b/2}\, x^{-1-b/2}
\end{equation}
on $f(x)$, which is also asymptotic to $f(x)$ (as $x\to\infty$). So, 
\begin{equation}
 G(x):=\int_x^\infty g(u)\,du=2ca^{-a/2-b/2}\, x^{-b/2}/b
\end{equation}
is an upper bound on the tail probability $P(X\ge x)$ for $X\sim F_{a,b}$ and $x>0$. Also, by l'Hospital's rule, this bound is asymptocally exact:
\begin{equation}
 P(X\ge x)\sim G(x). 
\end{equation}